# R: Google Distance Matrix API request rate limit exceeded

Tags: r, api

I know that similar questions have been asked before, but from what I've been able to gather, none of the answers seem to apply to my case.

What I'm trying to do is replicate this, but in the R language :   [Computing the optimal road trip across the us](http://www.randalolson.com/2015/03/08/computing-the-optimal-road-trip-across-the-u-s/)

Everything works perfectly until I ask the Googles for the distance matrix for more than 10 locations. In my script (to follow) I list my API key, and on the API website I can see that my successful runs of the program (when the number of locations is less than 10) increase my usage for the day, so I know that my API is working... I think.

What I don't understand is why do I receive the "rate limit exceeded" error for, say, a distance matrix with 11 locations? If I have 1,500 requests left, I should certainly not have any issues, right? I should add that I am not familiar with other programming languages such as Java and Python, so that could explain part of my confusion.

Here be the relevant code:

```
   # Request object from API
    r <- GET(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json",
    query = list(
        origins = places,
        destinations = places,
        key = "INSERT API KEY HERE")
    )

    stop_for_status(r)
    distances <- content(r)
```

The variable 'places' is simply a list containing the locations that I want distances to/from.

Answer (score 1):

[RTM](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits)?

> Each query sent to the Google Maps Distance Matrix API is limited by
>   the number of allowed elements, where **the number of origins times the
>   number of destinations defines the number of elements**.
>
> The Google Maps Distance Matrix API has the following limits in place:
>   Standard Usage Limits
>
> Users of the standard API:
>
> - 2,500 free elements per day
> - **100 elements per query**
> - 100 elements per 10 seconds

Ergo: I think you have to split it up into several queries, with a 10 seconds pause in between, in order to get the full distance matrix.